# Replacing CSS classes with more generic ones

Tags: css

I'm currently working on refactoring a large amount of CSS, and a common trend I'm seeing is that several classes have been created for a very specific item on a page. Rather than trying to describe what they do, the classes are named things like "PressReleaseText", or "SpecLabel", etc. Most of these just define one item, like a font-size or a color.

I'm wondering if it would be better to just create several utility classes, like `.fontSize140 {font-size: 140%;}`, `.bgColorWhite{ background-color: white;}`, and utilize those in place of all the duplication occurring across the current set of classes.

Are there any drawbacks to doing this? The point where it becomes blurry is if a current class has 3 attributes set, like color, background color, and font size, and I already have generic classes for all three of those, would my class definition in the html just look something like `class="white bgColorBlue fontSize140"`. That just seems excessive.

Comment: +1 because I wish more designers would consider the implications of such a practice before adopting it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is absolutely a **horrible** practice. It's 10x worse than the current class names that you're trying to replace. Consider the following class names:

- `fontSize140`
- `bgColorWhite`
- `marginTop150`

These are obviously very descriptive class names. The problem is that they describe the *styles* behind the class, not the *content* that it styles. While this can be easier to read in HTML, it will be a complete nightmare in the future when and if you decide to make even the tiniest redesign.

For example, let's say we just applied these three classes to a block of text. It has a font size of 140%, a white background, and a top margin of 150px. That's all fine--until we decide that it needs to be 90% font, a blue background, and no top margin. Now, not only do you have to change the CSS declarations, you have to either:

- (1) edit *every instance* of the class in the HTML to be `fontSize90bgColorBlueNoTopMargin` or whatever; or
- (2) leave the class name alone and leave an extremely confusing class name in the HTML.

Either way it will be a massive pain for you in the future, whereas the current class names (e.g., `specLabel`, `pressReleaseText`) appropriately describe the *content* that they style; their styles can be easily changed without affecting the content inside of them, and thereby never affecting the name of the class.

Comment: Yeah, great points. I think I've been starring at this so long I'm seeing optimizations where I shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the point of CSS is to separate the content from the presentation, to make it easier to alter the presentation without altering the content. If you have `class="white bgColorBlue fontSize140"` all over the place, you have defeated this goal; you might as well just go with `style="color: white; background-color: blue; font-size: 140%"`. Your classes should say what you *mean* not what you want it to look like.

If you find yourself repeating certain settings for lots of classes, like the following

```
.PreReleaseText { font-size: 140% }
.SpecLabel { font-size: 140%; background-color: white }
.SomeOtherThing { font-size: 140% }
```

You can instead combine several of them into one single rule

```
.PreReleaseText, .SpecLabel, .SomeOtherThing { font-size: 140% }
.SpecLabel { background-color: white }
```

If you really do just have several classes that are synonyms of each other, you might want to think about why that is. Why are all of those styled the same way? Is there some class name you can come up with that encompasses all of those uses? Or is it just incidental that they happen to be styled the same way? If it's just incidental, then they should have separate rules, so you can easily update the styles of each class independently. If there is some unifying theme, then perhaps you should merge them into a single class.

Remember to consider what will happen in different media, or in a redesign. Imagine that the company is bought out, and you want to change the color scheme to match the new corporate colors, without doing a full redesign. If you have a `.bgColorWhite` class, but only some of the things labelled with that class should change to a new color in the redesign, you'll have to go through all of your templates and markup again to separate out the classes, but if you labelled them with more meaningful classes, you may be able to just tweak the colors in the appropriate classes.

These are some general guidelines; you should always use what works best for you. If you had a more specific example, I might be able to suggest a better way of refactoring your classes for your specific need.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a right and wrong way to do this as far as I'm concerned. It depends on knowing how often you'll reuse things and what makes it easiest to understand the CSS. I've often seen those general things like .fontSize140 end up causing problems later on when you have to make changes. I prefer in most cases to group classes but keep the individual names.

So I might have

```
.Thing1,
.Thing2,
.Thing3 { font-size:14px; }

.Thing1 { font-weight:bold; }
.Thing2 { font-size:italic; }
```

Instead of having

```
.font14 { font-size:14px; }
```

And then still needing the .Thing1 and .Thing2 clases.

That was I can always change the CSS easily later without having to worry what is sharing that common .fontSize140 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from getting too general like `.fontSomeSize`. That said i generally try and use classes that define things as logical "types" or "objects" for example `.ruled-list` or `.summary`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

Use a css preprocessor like sass.

```
/* define app/website colors */

$main-color: #223c61;
$secondary-color: #2954a2;
$accent-color: #4cceac;

/* some example css classes */
.text-main { color: $main-color; }
.bg-secondary { background-color: $secondary-color; }
.bg-accent { background-color: $accent-color; }

/* define app/website spacings */

$spacing-xs: 10px;
$spacing-sm: 15px;
$spacing-md: 25px;
$spacing-lg: 35px;

/* some example css classes */
.padding-up-xs { padding-top: $spacing-xs; }
.padding-down-lg { padding-bottom: $spacing-lg; }
.margin-left-md { margin-left: $spacing-md; }
```

The above code has generic css classes, but it is not bound to a specific value. For some very specific styling, you can always make a custom css file to account for that.

I see a lot of people using custom margins and paddings throughout their css. See the code below.

```
.blog-post-sidebar-right { margin-top: 14px; }
.news-post-bottom-text { margin-bottom: 23px; }
```

As a rule of thumb, I always use 4/5 predefined margins and paddings. And not some arbitrary number you make up on the fly.

So why not define generic css classes to use them. I took this same idea an applied it to all of my css. Now I can have the same code base in every project.

Because you now use a css preprocessor, it's easy to maintain, flexible and easy to extend.

Im not saying this is the best option, but it does the job for me.