# How to escape quotes in Less variable which stores a color name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, less

I am working on a HTML/CSS project. I want to create classes for labels and texts based on the color. For example

```
text-red{
    color: red;
}

label-white{
    color: white;
}
```

To do this I am trying to create a mixin which accepts a name and a color as argument and creates this class. I wrote the following mixin :

```
.mixin(@name, @color) {
    .text-@{name} {
        color: @color !important;
    }
    .label-@{name} {
        color: @color !important;
    }
}

.mixin('white', white);
```

This gives me the following output

```
.text-'white'{ /* notice the quotes*/
    color: #ffffff
}
```

If I run this mixin as .mixin(white, white); I get

```
.text-#ffffff{
    color: #ffffff
}
```

How can I create a class like text-white using a mixin?

Comment: If you do this [you're gonna have a bad time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687763/replacing-css-classes-with-more-generic-ones/3687819#3687819). You might as well use inline styles.

Comment: I understand. I will think about the possibilities. Thanks for pointing to the posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [LESS "e" function reference](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e):

```
e(@string); // escape string content
```

If you use the function `e` you'll get the correct result.

```
.mixin(@name, @color) {
    .text-@{name} {
        color: @color !important;
    }
    .label-@{name} {
        color: @color !important;
    }
}

.mixin(e('white'), white);
```

You can also create a variable and then use it for multiple purposes:

```
@whiteLiteral: e('white');
//mixin declaration code
.mixin(@whiteLiteral, white);
```

Comment: Great! It works Like charm. I also tried using it with ~'white' and that worked too.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same thing :)

Comment: And if I remember correctly the only difference is that `~` evaluates it too(for example with variables), while `e` doesn't evaluate anything, just returns the string as-is.

Answer (score 1):

LightStyle is right but if you have many **named** color to set, you could use a recursive loop with a list of string color like this :

```
.recursive-loop(@list_size, @list) when (@list_size > 0) {

    // Get the current color from the list @list at index @list_size
    @current_color: e( extract(@list, @list_size) );


    .myclass1-@{current_color} {
        color: @current_color;
    }

    .myclass2-@{current_color} {
        background-color: @current_color;
    }

    //etc...

    // until the end of list
    .recursive-loop( (@list_size - 1), @list)
}

.mixin-color(){

    // Add color you need to this list and get size of it.
    @list: "black", "dimgrey", "grey", "lightgrey", "white", "red", "blue", "green";
    @list_size: length(@list);

    // Call recursive loop with the preview list
    .recursive-loop(@list_size, @list);

}

// mixin call
.mixin-color();
```

I hope it will help...